# Seeking Functional Programming Lexicon

Tags: functional-programming

Knowing the argot of a field helps me a lot, especially since it allows me to converse intelligently with those who know a lot more than I, so I would like to find a good lexicon of Functional Programming terms.

E.g., I repeatedly encounter these: Functor, Arrow, Category, Kleisli, Monad, Monoid, a veritable zoo of Morphisms, etc. I also notice many of these appear with prefixes such as "covariant", "co-", "endo-" etc.

Of these, I can say I actually understand Monoid and Covariant and sort of get Monad, but the rest are still gibberish to me. (Note that I don't mean this list as exhaustive and I'm not looking to have these defined or described for me here, I'm looking for learning resources.)

Can someone point me towards an FP lexicon? It need not be on-line, as long as it's possible to find it (and it's not a rare volume for which I'd have to pay many tens of dollars).

Comment: Wikipedia always works: "A monad or triple is an (endo-)functor, together with two associated natural transformations. Monads are important in the theory of pairs of adjoint functors, and they generalize closure operators on partially ordered sets to arbitrary categories. The notion of "algebras for a monad" generalizes classical notions from universal algebra, and in this sense, monads can be thought of as "theories"." .................. Alright, maybe not always the best resource.

Comment: Funny. While I like chasing English words through the dictionary, these just don't provide the same fun.

Comment: To be fair to Wikipedia, it has a separate article about monads as used by FP, and it's a little less mathematical.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As other answers have pointed out, to really understand those terms you have to study Category Theory. However, Category Theory is very abstract and may not help you build up intuition immediately. To see the abstract concepts in action, I highly recommend the Typeclassopedia ([PDF](http://www.haskell.org/wikiupload/8/85/TMR-Issue13.pdf)) ([blog announcement](http://byorgey.wordpress.com/2009/02/16/the-typeclassopedia-request-for-feedback/)).

Answer (score 7):

These aren't functional-programming terms; they're terms from Category Theory.  It's true that a handful of elite functional programmers seem to use category theory to get insights into functional programming (Conal Elliott, Ralf Hinze, Chung-Chieh Shan, phone your office), but these people are in the minority.  Regarding these terms, I struggled with Pierce's book but I don't know a better source—although [Dan Piponi](http://sigfpe.com/) has a lot of related material on his blog; I encourage you to look there. (**2012 update**: Harold Simmons has a new book on category theory that looks quite good, and it was very well reviewed by *Computing Reviews* [behind a paywall].  The only complaint is that the examples are all from math and not from computing.)

Some words you might hear from functional progammers: "map function", "fold function", "higher-order function", "point-free programming", "sum type",  "product type", "catamorphism", "Church encoding", "calculating programs", "type-directed programming", "proper tail call", "accumulating parameter".  I don't know of a good lexicon gathered in one place.  Graham Hutton's book *Programming in Haskell* might be a place to start, or the older book by Richard Bird and Phil Wadler.

Comment: "... a handful of elite functional programmers seem to use category theory to get insights into functional programming ..." I guess I've fallen in with a bad crowd...

Comment: @Randall: No, you're a lucky man. I wish I could do it.  I'm going to try again this summer...

Comment: Norman, you have no idea how much better you've made me feel about all the mind-bending Haskell papers I've read over the last few months. I recently heard someone joke that understanding Haskell requires *two* PhDs. If you're struggling, there's hope for the rest of us...

Comment: Excuse me: far from being able to correct somebody like you, but aren't the people that you call a "minority" the ones who shape the Haskell culture? General definitions of e.g. catamorphism are usually given in the context of category theory.

Comment: @Blaisorblade: Haskell culture is a big tent; there is plenty of shaping to go around.  Certainly Ralf Hinze, who is utterly brilliant at using category theory, has shaped Haskell culture.  But Simon Peyton Jones, who has also had a huge influence, writes tons of papers that hardly mention category theory.  (And many of the newest movers and shakers are using dependent types, which is another kettle of fish, but one I understand better...)

Answer (score 5):

Many of the terms you used as example are from Category Theory, and the best resource I know in the circumstances is Benjamin Pierce's "Basic Category Theory for Computer Scientists"

Comment: It's not even that expensive: $21 in the US. http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0262660717?redirect=true

Comment: A colleague suggested that this text does not align so well with current FP usage. He pointed out that it doesn't deal with Monads at all, probably the greatest single obsession of the FP world (or so it seems). And the plethora of morphisms I hear of don't appear, either. In short, it seems to be category theory primer for programmers more than an compendium of FP techniques.